# How to change \pgfplotstableset for different parts of a document?

Tags: pgfplotstable

In the documentation for the pgfplotstable package you can find the following in the introduction:

> Key-value pairs can be set in two ways:
>
> 1. As default settings for the complete document (or maybe a part of the document), using
>      \pgfplotstableset{⟨options⟩}. For example, the document’s preamble may contain \pgfplotstableset{fixed zerofill,precision=3}
>      to configure a precision of 3 digits after the period, including zeros to get exactly 3 digits for all fixed point numbers.

The **or maybe a part of the document** is what I am interested in.

I have different `\pgfplotstableset{⟨options⟩}` defined via `\newcommand` and intended to switch between them as needed (more or less for each table). Sadly I have not really been able to get this to work.

- Is this possible at all?
- Could you point me to an example document where it has been done?

Thanks!

---

I will try to explain a bit more in detail what my problem is.

In the preamble I have created multiple new commands such as:

```
\newcommand{\CCforTABSTable}{\pgfplotstableset{
    reset styles,
    disable rowcol styles=false,
    col sep=&,
    header=false,
%   precision=2,
%   row sep=\\,
    columns={0, 5, 8},
    columns/0/.style={reset styles,string type,column type={L{.5\linewidth}}, column name={Location}},
    columns/5/.style={reset styles,string type,column type={C{.1\linewidth}}, column name={0d}},
    columns/8/.style={reset styles,string type,column type={C{.1\linewidth}}, column name={1d}},
begin table=\begin{longtable},
    every first row/.append style={ %
            before row={\midrule
        \endfirsthead
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
            \midrule
        \endhead
            \bottomrule
        \endfoot
            \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
    }, 
},
end table=\end{longtable},
}
}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\IDATableTypeT}{\pgfplotstableset{  %Type T
    reset styles,
    disable rowcol styles=true,
    header=true,
    precision=2,
    create on use/thiws/.style={create col/expr={(\thisrow{thiws1}+\thisrow{thiws2}+\thisrow{thiws3}+\thisrow{thiws4})/4}},
    create on use/thiw/.style={create col/expr={(\thisrow{thiw1}+\thisrow{thiw2}+\thisrow{thiw3}+\thisrow{thiw4})/4}},
    %
columns={time, thwaterin, thwaterout, thf, thp, thc, thiws, thiw, tha, thmr, thop},
columns/time/.style={column name={Step}, fixed},
columns/thwaterin/.style={column name={$\tHWaterIn$}, fixed zerofill, precision=1, fixed},
columns/thwaterout/.style={column name={$\tHWaterOut$},  fixed zerofill, precision=1, fixed},
columns/thf/.style={column name={$\tHF$}, fixed zerofill, precision=1, fixed},
columns/thp/.style={column name={$\tHP$}, fixed zerofill, precision=1, fixed},
columns/thc/.style={column name={$\tHC$}, fixed zerofill, precision=1, fixed},
columns/thiws/.style={column name={$\tHIws$}, fixed zerofill, precision=1, fixed},
columns/thiw/.style={column name={$\tHIw$}, fixed zerofill, precision=1, fixed},
columns/tHA/.style={column name={$\tHA$}, fixed zerofill, precision=1, fixed},
columns/thmr/.style={column name={$\tHMr$}, fixed zerofill, precision=1, fixed},
columns/thop/.style={column name={$\tHOp$}, fixed zerofill, precision=1, fixed},
%   row sep=\\,
begin table=\begin{longtable},
every first row/.append style={ %
            before row={\midrule
        \endfirsthead
            \multicolumn{10}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
            \midrule
        \endhead
            \bottomrule
        \endfoot
            \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
    }, 
},
end table=\end{longtable},
}
}
```

In the main document I now have first:

```
\CCforTABSTable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[every head row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{Case: bla} %
    \label{tab:test}\\ %
    \toprule},}
] {\CCData/results/1318AaBb-1day.txt}
```

and the later:

```
\IDATableTypeT % defined in pgfplots.tex
\pgfplotstabletypeset[every head row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{jaja} %
    \label{tab:11855-4_HighWallHeatCond_TypeT}\\ %
    \toprule},}
] {\IDAData/11855-4_HighWallHeatCond.prn}
```

Until now I have gotten different errors but the one that I do not understand is this one:

```
PGFPlots: reading {Data/IDA/11855-4_HighWallHeatCond.prn}

./SimplyTabs/Appendix/ValidationIDA.tex:14: Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, 
could not retrieve column 'time' from table 'Data/IDA/11855-4_HighWallHeatCond.prn'.
Please check spelling (or introduce name aliases)..
```

However the file reads:

```
time         order        qhc          qhcirc       qhcontot     qhf          qhiws1       qhiws2       qhiws3       qhiws4       qhradtot     tha          thc          thf          thiw1        thiw2        thiw3        thiw4        thiws1       thiws2       thiws3       thiws4       thmr         thmrandt_1   thmrandt_2   thop         thp          thwaterin    thwaterout
4679.000000       1.0000       209.93      -880.68       30.000       32.953      -20.663      -17.220      -20.663      -17.220       10.000       23.330       21.846       22.378       22.902       22.902       22.902       22.902       22.900       22.900       22.900       22.900       22.481       23.330      -7.1583       22.763       21.232       20.000       20.707    
4680.000000       1.0000       125.03      -799.28       30.000       5.0923      -20.864      -17.386      -20.864      -17.386       10.000       22.306       21.584       22.096       22.397       22.397       22.397       22.397       22.395       22.395       22.395       22.395       22.105       22.306      -7.1583       22.202       21.110       20.000       20.637
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you defined styles and selected the desired style when needed. If you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem, it might easier to give more specific advice.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: I will try to do so but that will take some time. However one question that might be easy to answer without an MWE. It there an option for \pgfplotstableset{} that resets all values to there defaults? That would likely be all I need. I found "reset styles" and "disable rowcol styles" but that does not seem to be enough.

Comment: As with all s/w, even if there such a documented option you can't just assume it works without testing it. So, a MWE _should_ be provided for that as well. As you said you found `reset styles` but it didn't work.

Comment: I have added some code now but its far from a MWE. I will try to do this tomorrow (past midnight here).

Comment: Perhaps `disable rowcol styles=true, reset styles` will do what you desire. But without a MWE I can't test it.

Comment: Options live until the current TeX group ends. A TeX group is started by `{` and ended by `}`. It is also started by `\begin{<someenvironment>}` and ended by `\end{<someenvironment>}`. If you surrent parts of your document with curly braces, all key assignments inside of the braces will be limited to these braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't find a reset style key, I recommend you define the stles you want to apply to *all* tables, for instance:

```
\pgfplotstableset{zerofill}
```

and prepare different styles for the various things you want to control:

```
\pgfplotstableset{My Style1/.append style={precision=3}}
\pgfplotstableset{My Style2/.append style={precision=1}}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

%% Setting for ENTIRE document
\pgfplotstableset{zerofill}

%% Settings that you selectively want to control
\pgfplotstableset{My Style1/.append style={precision=3}}
\pgfplotstableset{My Style2/.append style={precision=1}}


%\usepackage{filecontents}% <--- Commented out so as to now overwrite sample.csv
  \begin{filecontents*}{sample.csv}
    Column A, Column B, Column C
       99, 98, 96
       88, 87, 84
  \end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{sample.csv}\MySampleData

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[My Style1]\MySampleData
\bigskip\par
\pgfplotstabletypeset[My Style2]\MySampleData

\end{document}
```